# Cannot add or checkout README.md/readme.md file to repository

Tags: git

Our team recently updated the readme file for our repository. The issue is after the first person was able to push it up, anyone who has pulled it down is unable to add it to a commit or check it out.

git add --all results in it being left as modified

git checkout -- readme.md results in README.md being left as modified

git checkout -- README.md results in readme.md being left as modified

I tried adding this to .gitignore as well which resulted in both readme.md and .gitignore being modified.

Any help troubleshooting would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. I made another change on the Readme.md file and tried again. This time it allowed me to commit and push the changes.